# With Azure table storage, how can I fall back to a secondary storage account?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, fallback, geo-replication

I am developing an Azure application (C#, .NET 6, ASP.NET Core) that uses Azure blob storage as well as table storage.

I have geo-redundancy enabled on my storage account (RA_GRS) so that if my main storage account goes down, a read-only copy will be available in another Azure region.

When reading from blob storage, as far as I understand, I should be able to get it to automatically fall back to the secondary address by setting the *GeoRedundantSecondaryUri* property like this (using the **Azure.Storage.Blobs** NuGet, version 12.8.4):

```cs
    return new BlobServiceClient(
        new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/"),
        sharedKeyCredential,
        new BlobClientOptions
        {
            GeoRedundantSecondaryUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/")
        });
```

Can I do something similar when reading from table storage?

The classes I am using are **CloudStorageAccount**, **CloudTableClient** and **CloudTable** (from the **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table** NuGet, version 1.0.8). None of them seem to have a property similar to **BlobClientOptions**.*GeoRedundantSecondaryUri*. I don't know whether there is another set of classes I ought to use instead.

Is there any easy way to make Azure table storage fall back automatically, or will I have to implement it myself?

Comment: Can you share the SDK name and version you’re using to access Table Storage?

Comment: Good point. Added. I am using Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.8.4 and Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table 1.0.8.

Comment: Does [the code of ServiceRestClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/src/TableServiceClient.cs) useful to you ?